# Wrong maven compilation error (works in eclipse)

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting a compilation error when I compile using maven but works in eclipse. Both are using the same JDK:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_35, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] /blablabla.../myClass.java:    [78,107] inconvertible types
[ERROR] found   : java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object>
[ERROR] required: java.util.Collection<? extends org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroup>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

And this is the code (no compilation error in eclipse):

```
Collection<? extends MessageGroup> collection = (Collection<? extends MessageGroup>) this.groupMap.values();
```

I know that this is a pretty recursive issue, I've found a few posts asking the same, but seems that nobody has a standar fix. Some people say that works with different JDK version. I have tested with 1.6.0_30, 1.6.0_31, 1.6.0_32 and 1.6.0_35 and all fail.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the source and target version of the compiler plugin? See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Yes --> <source>1.6</source><target>1.6</target>

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use the compiler from the JDK. It only needs the reference to the JDK for the libraries! So it's entirely possible that the Maven compiler accepts some code while the JDK compiler (which Maven uses by default) doesn't. And most times when I saw those two diverge, the Eclipse compiler was the standard-conforming one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect eclipse isn't using the JDK you think it is. Try using type erasure.

```
Collection<? extends MessageGroup> collection = 
        (Collection<? extends MessageGroup>)
                (Collection) this.groupMap.values();
```

Comment: Double checked installed JRE and build path in eclipse... as expected is the same (1.6.0_35). Anyway.... type erasure works!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I knew about type erasure as a concept during compilation, but not as an explicit coding technique.  Thanks for the answer, it's what I needed too.